# How many keys are possible for a substitution cipher using the (lowercase) English alphabet?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know that The number of possible keys (E) in a monoalphabetic cipher is 26!

However I know that this will assign A to a certain other letter in the alphabet and then B to a certain letter in the alphabet except for the one assigned to A. I was wondering what the total number of keys would be possible for a substitution cipher using the lowercase English alphabet **and** leaving some or all characters unchanged are also allowed.

Comment: Your $26!$ includes many examples where some characters are left unchanged (about $1-e^{-1} \approx 63.2\%$ of the examples), including $1$ example where they all are

Comment: Oh thank you! So, 26! keys are possible for a substitution cipher where characters can also be left unchanged.

Comment: That is correct.  If you want to leave none of the characters unchanged, then you are considering [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).